# Three js particle system with mouse interaction

Tags: three.js

I try change behaviour particles with this example:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_particles_random

to more like this:
http://minimal.be/lab/fluGL/

Now when I simply change this fragment of code:

```
            for ( i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i ++ ) {

                var object = scene.children[ i ];

                if ( object instanceof THREE.ParticleSystem ) {

                    object.rotation.z = time * ( i < 4 ? i + 1 : - ( i + 1 ) );

                }

            }
```

Into that:

```
            for ( i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i ++ ) {

                var object = scene.children[ i ];

                if ( object instanceof THREE.ParticleSystem ) {

                    object.position.x = mouseX;
                    object.position.y = -mouseY;
                }
            }
```

All particles move globally without change distance and velocity. 
The change, which I present is only example. How to modify the code, to avoid global changes in move particles? Do I have to change something in shaders? Or Particle System in three.js is enough to create mouse attractor behaviour?